# Setting height of tableviewcell to match bottom to the tab bar's top

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitableview

Currently I have a custom table view cell and I want to match the re-useable cell's bottom to the top of the tab bar, wrt given iPhone size dimensions (i.e. as dynamic as it can be). Basically, on the first run without a finger scroll, the cell should fit the area from navigation bar's bottom to the tab bar's top. I believe it is just like this for apps like instagram, vine etc.

How can I achieve this, especially without using some library etc.? Do I have to use something like a pod for ease of implementation or current limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Set the rowHeight Property of the cell

```
[tableView setRowHeight:CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)];
```

This will return the height starting from navBar bottom edge and Tabbar's top edge.

Answer (score -1):

You could also set the cell's height in the table view delegate method below:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
}
```